# How should I check the sorted statement in jasmine or javascript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, jasmine

I am writing a spec for a Backbone.Collection.
I would like to check the following statement in a unit test javascript using jasmine:

```
should the models be ordered by starting with the most recent.
```

The key value in the model to check is the `id` (which is an integer).

For example the collection is sorted if it looks like this:

```
[
{id: 5, ….}, // the most recent
{id: 2, ...},
{id: 1, ...}
]
```

My question is:
1) is there a jasmine method to make this kind of check?
2) if not, what is the best way to make it in javascript? maybe using some library like underscore.

Comment: You'd like to check whether an array of object is sorted by its id?

Comment: @SiGanteng yes, you got it. I would like to check if the array of objects is sorted by id

Answer (score 2):

You could do a for loop, not sure if there's built-in that checks what you want:

```
    var max = arr[0].id;
    var sorted = true;

    for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
       if(max > arr[i].id) {
           sorted = false; break;
       }
    }

    alert(sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you have set in your collection a `comparator` that will keep your collection sorted.

In your test, create 3 items out of order, let's say:

```
collection = new MyCollection();
collection.add({id: 1, bar: 'foo1'});
collection.add({id: 5, bar: 'foo5'});
collection.add({id: 3, bar: 'foo3'});
```

Then making sure the comparator works, becomes as easy as:

```
expect(_.pluck(collection.models, 'id')).toEqual([5, 3, 1]);
```